# SQL TSQL DATA TYPES IN() MONTHS

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a data type question.  The following line of code works on our database:

```
WHERE e_ru IN (5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250)
```

Now I would like to insert a different set of numbers for `e_ru` for each month.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME, @MonthOfYear TINYINT, @RUsToAudit NVARCHAR
SET @StartDate = (dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())),0)+15)
SET @EndDate = (dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DATEADD(month, 0, GETDATE())),0)+14)
SET @MonthOfYear = DATEPART(month, GETDATE())
SET @RUsToAudit =
CASE
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 1 THEN (SELECT 5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250)
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 2 THEN (SELECT 5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250)
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 3 THEN (SELECT 5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250)
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 4 THEN (SELECT 5460,5470,5500)
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 5 THEN (SELECT 5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250)
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 6 THEN (SELECT 5530,5910)
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 7 THEN (SELECT 5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250)
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 8 THEN (SELECT 5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250)
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 9 THEN (SELECT 5460,5470,5500)
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 10 THEN (SELECT 5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250)
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 11 THEN (SELECT 5530,5910)
WHEN @MonthOfYear = 12 THEN (SELECT 5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250)
END
SELECT          @StartDate AS 'Report Start Date', @EndDate AS 'Report End Date', @MonthOfYear AS 'Month', @RUsToAudit AS 'Programs'
```

Comment: Sorry, I started the code lines with four spaces but the page did not read it as designating code.  hmmm?

Comment: The question I am trying to ask is: in SQL how do I load an array of int data types into a variable?  The IN() function will then do the right thing with this array of ints.

Comment: @PowderSnorkel - SQL uses tables to relate data.  This is what you want.  Use a table not a CASE statement or an Array.

Comment: Dim atmospherePressures(,,,) As Short
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x397t1yt(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks Hogan, will do.

Comment: Ooops, but then how do I set the values differently for each month?Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to make a permanent table in your database to store this information.  Specifically, a table with MonthNumber and ListItem (both integers), and then use the query that Hogan suggests.

It appears to me as though you are (currently) hard coding business rules in to the database.  By separating these values in to another table, you can easily change the functionality by changing the data in the table instead of diving in to the code to make a change.

This may take a little more time to set up, but it will be a more elegant solution in the long run (as business process change).

Answer (score 0):

For example, this would work, but probably is not exactly what you want-- I'd need to know what you are trying to do to make the correct data model

```
WITH dataTable AS
(
   SELECT 1 AS Month,  '5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250' AS List
UNION ALL
   SELECT 2  AS Month, '5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250' AS List
UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3  AS Month, '5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250' AS List
UNION ALL
   SELECT 4  AS Month, '5460,5470,5500' AS List
UNION ALL
   SELECT 5  AS Month, '5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250' AS List
UNION ALL
   SELECT 6  AS Month, '5530,5910' AS List
UNION ALL
   SELECT 7  AS Month, '5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250' AS List
UNION ALL
   SELECT 8  AS Month, '5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250' AS List
UNION ALL
   SELECT 9  AS Month, '5460,5470,5500' AS List
UNION ALL
   SELECT 10 AS Month, '5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250' AS List
UNION ALL
   SELECT 11 AS Month, '5530,5910' AS List
UNION ALL
   SELECT 12 AS Month, '5420,5410,5550,6230,6240,6250' AS List
)
SELECT @RUsToAudit = List
FROM dataTable WHERE Month = @MonthOfYear
```

If you plan on using this as the `IN()` part of another select then do it this way:

```
WITH dataTable AS
(
   SELECT 1 AS Month, 5420 as ID
 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 AS Month, 5410 as ID
 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 AS Month, 5550 as ID
 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 AS Month, 6230 as ID
 -- etc
)
SELECT * 
FROM table
JOIN dataTable on table.ID = dataTable.ID AND dataTable.Month = @MonthOfYear
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE table.ID IN (SELECT ID from dataTable WHERE dataTable.Month = @MonthOfYear)
```

**Having a string variable with the contents of IN won't work.**

Comment: Yes, I think one of those approaches will work.  Thanks so much.